# gVIM Windows grouping and backreferencing - E486: Pattern not found

Tags: windows, vim

I try to substitute the text:

```
abc def ghi
```

and delete the third word:

For this I use:

```
.s:\(\w+ \w+\) \w+:\1/
```

following this tutorial: [4.5 Grouping and Backreferences](https://vimregex.com/)

Unfortunately when I execute this command I  get

```
E486: Pattern not found: \(\w+ \w+\) w+
```

Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: You need to escape your quantifier, +, to \+

Comment: It works! @PatrickBacon please post it as an answer, so I can accept it. Thank you.

Comment: The linked resource actually uses `\+` so it's just a matter of following it carefully.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**The Quantifier, +, Needs to be Escaped**

Your pattern is fine, it is just that you need to escape your quantifier, +.

You had this:

```
.s:\(\w+ \w+\) \w+:\1/
```

Change it to this:

```
.s:\(\w\+ \w\+\) \w\+:\1/
```

When in doubt, look it up in Vim's help files.

`:help pattern`     /*notice section 3 covers magic and section 5 covers quantifiers*/

Some people like using magic which reduce the amount of escaping. You might want to peruse this.